# How to put button outside of form

Tags: php, jquery, forms, button

I have a form that come with action like this.

```
<form action="edit.php" method="post">
.
.

<button class="btn btn-success"  name="submit_mult" type="submit">Edit</button>
</form>
```

I need this to use for first button, and now I want to use same form for second button this time is for delete, but is because this form action using for "edit.php",  **so I use formaction="delete.php,this will This overrides the action attribute of the form when you click on that button.**

But I want the second button to be show outside of form not inside of form, and I tried to figure out how that works..

Wrote like this...

```
 <div id="delete"><button class="btn btn-success" formaction="Multi_Edit/delete.php"  name="submit_mult" type="submit">delete</button></div>
```

Is not working when I put this button in outside of form, but is works fine inside of form.

How can I solve this to make works that button outside of forms with formaction="delete.php" if this works fine with jquery, how to write that in jquery!

Comment: make a 2nd form around it. So it becomes `<form ...><button>delete</button></form>`. You can have multiple forms in a single HTML page.

Comment: Why not just evaluate which button was clicked within the php script used for the action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

put and id to the form

```
<form action="edit.php" method="post" id="myForm" >
.
.
```

and an id to the button

```
<div id="delete"><button class="btn btn-success" formaction="Multi_Edit/delete.php"  name="submit_mult" id="myDeleteButton" type="submit">delete</button></div>
```

then via jquery handle the form submit

```
$("#myDeleteButton").click(function(){
     $("#myForm").attr('action','Multi_Edit/delete.php');
     $("#myForm").submit();
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much is works great with jquery, i never thought about using   .attr, again thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `form` attribute, `form="theForm"`:

```
<form action="edit.php" method="post" id="theForm">...</form>
<div id="delete"><button form="theForm" class="btn btn-success" formaction="Multi_Edit/delete.php"  name="submit_mult" type="submit">delete</button></div>
```

See here: http://www.sitepoint.com/the-html5-form-attribute/